# Magento + ShipSync Wrong Dimensions sent to FedEx (LxWxH)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, fedex

Running Magento CE 1.7.0.2 with ShipSync V5
Canadian Company Shipping to Canadian addresses only.
Request shipping as account rates extending discount to users.

Issue we're having is that if a package rate is being calculated incorrectly.

**ShipSync doesn't seem to install the Length Height and Width attributes- and breaks the FedEx module from sending dimensions to the FedEx API**

*Example:*

0.4 lbs and dimensions of 5x5x4 the XML being sent to FedEx is 0.4 lbs and dimensions 16x13x10.

If the FedEx limit is true (minimum 2 lbs shipping) and we set the product weight to 2lbs and zero out the dimensions like so:

2 lbs and dimensions of 0x0x0 the XML sent is 2 lbs and dimensions 16x12x1

None of these match packages that exist (and we really don't want to use pre-defined packaging.

Edit:
Seems there was an update to V5 https://github.com/five23/shipsync-community

It looks like ShipSync is not installing the "Height, Width, & Length" attributes. I think this is the underlying issue with the above examples.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create `shipsync package` from `magento admin -> configuration -> shipping settings -> shipsync packages`..

**Your shipsync API is taking the nearest dimensioned package from your product's dimension..**

let me know if you want any further guidance...

Comment: I don't think this is the problem- the Length, width, and height dimensions are not even present at the product level.